# How to share data from an object class to an activity Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
object 
object V2RayServiceManager {

   //get live data from here
}

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

  //recieve live data here 
}
```

**
have tried using eventBus but doesn't work not receiving data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to approach is by using Reactive way

```
object V2RayServiceManager {

   fun getSource(): Observable {
       return Observable.create{ emitter ->
          emitter.onNext(10);
          emitter.onNext(11);
       } 
   }
}
```

Whenever source emits value like `source.onNext(11)` it will call who subscribed this source for example activity in your case.

MainActivity:

```
V2RayServiceManager.source.subscribe { data -> 
    // You will receive 10 and 11
}
```

When ever someone call `sendData` with value. It will trigger who ever subscribed this subject

Comment: Have tried using your method still failed to work , is it fine if you could have a look at my code, have been trying to work on this for about a year now cant get a solution to it.